# Keep reference to same instance C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I don't have experience with C++, and I would like to have a behaviour similar to this code, where I push some references to the same instance to the vector, and I modify the value of a field in all the instances. How is it possible to do that in C++?

Currently I have this code but the value of each elements in the vector is a new copy, How can I make that all the elements in the vector refer to the same instance?

```
vector<MyClass> vectorABC;
MyClass a;

for (auto i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        a = vectorABC.back();
    } else {
        a = MyClass();
    }
    a.field += 10;
    vectorABC.push_back(a);
}
```

EDIT:

As some people asked more information:

I want to generate the faces/triangles for render a cone, each faces/triangles have 3 vertex, and each vertex a position (x,y,z) and a normal (x,y,z).

The render function receive as parameter a vector of vertex and each 3 vertex is render into a triangle.

I want to calculate the normals as it is explain it [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/programmatically-generating-vertex-normals).

All faces in the cone share one of the vertex, the tip, and the other 2 with the neighbors. So in my loop where I calculate the position and the normal I want to be able to keep the reference to the same object for update the normal value of the vertex so the vertex's normal consider all the surface that share the same vertex.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n_triangles; i++) {
    // Calculate the positions of the 3 vertex
    // Where the first v0 is the tip the second v1 is from the vector.back()
    // and the third v2 is new
    // ...

    auto normal = cross(v2 - v0, v1 -v0);

    v0.normal += normal;
    v1.normal += normal;
    v2.normal += normal;

    vertices.push_back(v0);
    vertices.push_back(v1);
    vertices.push_back(v2);
}

for (auto& vertex : vertices) {
    vertex.normal.normalize();
}
```

This code doesn't update the previous values of v0 when I update the normal because it copies the vertex when I insert them in the vector. As I said I am newbie with c++ and I don't know which would be the best approach to keep the reference to a same vertex instance.

EDIT2:

As Basya Perlman suggested I implemented a solution with Smart pointers. Like the smooth algorithm needs two loop: one for calculate the normals and another one for normalize the normal vectors, I used the second one for create the vector that I will return to the render function.

```
vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>> vector_ptrs;
vector<MyClass> vertices;
shared_ptr<MyClass> v0, v1, v2, v3;
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < n_triangles; i++) {
    // Calculate the positions of the 3 vertex
    // Where the first v0 is the tip the second v1 is from the vector.back()
    // and the third v2 is new
    // ...

    auto normal = cross(v2->position - v0->position, v1->position -v0->position);

    v0->normal += normal;
    v1->normal += normal;
    v2->normal += normal;

    vector_ptrs.push_back(v0);
    vector_ptrs.push_back(v1);
    vector_ptrs.push_back(v2);
}

for (auto& vertex : vector_ptrs) {
    vertex->normal.normalize();
    vertices.push_back(vertex);
}
```

Thanks for your time. In the picture you can see the final result, I think the shadows are really smooth :)

[image: A picture of the final result]

Comment: [off topic]: `auto` is one more character than `int`.

Comment: You can't with `std::vector` unless using a `std::reference_wrapper` as element.

Comment: Important note: C++ doesn't automatically have references to object (like Java or C#), instead the default is to have distinct objects, and *values*. So you are in fact not pushing "references" into the vector but new *copies* as you noticed.

Comment: **user0042** is correct about references, but that creates a new problem with the code: if vector is populated by references, then changing field changes field for every vectorABC[i], since they would all refer to the same object — making it a glorified size() counter.

Comment: Also, can you please elaborate on the *actual* problem you have? The reason why you want to have a vector of references to the same object?Please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and think about how it relates to your question (asking for help about a solution to an for us unknown problem). Perhaps there are other ways, maybe even better ways, to solve the original problem?

Comment: Do you really want a vector of references, that all reference the same single object? That doesn't sound very likely. Also, in your last for loop you most likely wanted to use a reference `for (auto& vertex : vertices)`. Otherwise you perform the normalization on a copy, not on the element in the vector.

Comment: True I should use    for (auto& vertex : vertices), thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create pointers (or, better, smart pointers) to the one object, and make a vector of the (smart) pointers.  That might accomplish what you want.

With your added information, I see that this only partially helps you -- you can have pointers to the same vertex and they will all change when you update it, but you don't have the vector in the format you need to pass to the render function you are using.

You could have a convert function which takes the vector as I described it, loops over it, and creates a throwaway vector of copies just for passing to the render function.  This should work.  There might be a better way; I'll add more options if I come up with them.

Comment: I extended the question. If I change the content of the vector to smart pointers, there is a easy way to transform it to a vector<MyClass>? Do I need to loop over all the content of the vector to generate the vector<MyClass>? I don't have control over the render function and I need to return a vector<MyClass>.